# Network connection is being dropped while phone is locked

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am writing an enterprise application that needs to communicate with a server at certain intervals. Since this is for enterprise I have classified by app as VoIp so I have access to setKeepAliveTimeout() so I can communicate with the server using NSURLSession. In my plist file I have specified UIRequiresPersistentWiFI as well. For a simple test I have turned off WiFi. However it seems like the GSM network connection is dropped after a while after the phone goes to lock screen.

Is there something I am missing?

Also would I expect WiFi to also be dropped when the phone is sleeping? How can I maintain a network connection or bring it up again so I can send a HTTP request to my server?

Comment: You can maintain a tcp connection to the server with VoIP background mode and when server send packet to your client, system will wake it up then give your app several seconds to do some work.

Comment: So in iOS there is no other way for the device to send data at regular intervals while the phone is locked/sleeping?

Comment: Use `setKeepAliveTimeout:handler:` to make your app wake up at regular intervals, but the time is at least 600 seconds.

Comment: I am already doing this. But using NLURLSession even in the setKeepAliveTimeout callback is failing to connect when the phone is sleeping/locked